# Jquery Show and hide div in all hosts

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, show

I'm using AJAX call to click a button and show a div, **whose id is called not**, in all host's that are displaying that same page, then the div hides after n seconds, and appears if the button is clicked one more time.

**The problem** is that the div only appears and then hide in the host of the user that clicked the button and not in the others (if i remove the if statement it will appear on all host's, but it wont hide, and then appear again as the button is newly clicked)

Here is the JQUERY Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); // IE BUG -> caso contrário IE não faz refresh
    setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');}, 500);

    // setInterval(function() {$('#not').show().load('logs1.php').delay(5000).fadeOut();}, 500);

    var n=0;
    $('#submeter').click(function(){
        if(n==0){
            $('#not').show();
            setInterval(function() {$('#not').load('logs1.php');}, 500);
            n=1;
        }

        if(n==1){
            $('#not').delay(2000).fadeOut();
            n=0;
        }
    })
});
```

UPDATE logs.php:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","efansredes");
$results=$con->query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id DESC");

$i = 0;
while($row=$results->fetch_array()){
if($i %2 == 0)
{
  $class = 'even';
}
else
{
  $class = 'odd';
}
$i++;

// output da tabela
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr class='$class'>";
echo "<td>"."<b>".$row["username"]."</b>".": ".$row["msg"]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

UPDATE logs1.php

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","efansredes");
$results=$con->query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1");

$i = 0;
while($row=$results->fetch_array()){
if($i %2 == 0)
{
  $class = 'even';
}
else
{
  $class = 'odd';
}
$i++;

// output da tabela
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr class='$class'>";
echo "<td>"."<b>".$row["username"]."</b>".": ".$row["msg"]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Ok, it would be helpful to see logs1.php, logs.php :) without that, I can only see that you're toggling n on button click.

Comment: Question updated for logs and logs1.php.

Comment: Basically the important file here is logs1, not logs... logs1 is the one that appears inside #not div.